# How to temporarily replace Python class method without mocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I have been wondering about this behaviour when replacing a class method I observe in Python 3.8 and concluded I do not understand it. I suspect it may have something to do with loosing the `@classmethod` decorator or something similar, but am at a loss.

1. What exactly is going wrong there?
2. What is a good way to make the last case work **without using mocking libraries**?

**Note:** I know the code below is not the best practice. This is about trying to learn more about Python and understanding what is going on under the hood.

```
from unittest import mock


class SomeClass:
    @classmethod
    def hello(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__


class DerivedClass(SomeClass):
    pass


def test_works_as_expected():
    assert SomeClass.hello() == 'SomeClass'           # True
    assert DerivedClass.hello() == 'DerivedClass'     # True


def test_replace_with_mock():
    # This works just fine
    assert DerivedClass.hello() == 'DerivedClass'     # True

    with mock.patch.object(SomeClass, 'hello', new=lambda: 'replacement'):
        assert DerivedClass.hello() == 'replacement'  # True

    assert DerivedClass.hello() == 'DerivedClass'     # True


def test_this_does_not_work():
    assert DerivedClass.hello() == 'DerivedClass'     # True

    original_fn = SomeClass.hello
    SomeClass.hello = lambda: 'replacement'
    assert DerivedClass.hello() == 'replacement'      # True
    SomeClass.hello = original_fn                     # This should put things back in order, but does not

    assert DerivedClass.hello() == 'DerivedClass'     # AssertionError: assert 'SomeClass' == 'DerivedClass'

# After executing the above DerivedClass.hello() no longer works correctly in this module or in any other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the [Descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors)!

Consider this code:

```
hello1 = SomeClass.hello
hello2 = DerivedClass.hello
print(hello1())  # 'SomeClass'
print(hello2())  # 'DerivedClass'
```

`hello1` and `hello2` are different even though they both are retrieved from the same definition of `hello`.

This is because both ordinary functions *defined inside classes* and `classmethod`s implement the descriptor protocol, which is used whenever a value is retrieved from a class or an object.

`SomeClass.hello` (as well as `SomeClass().hello`) returns the underlying function with the `cls` argument (or `self` if it weren't a `classmethod`) to the class (or instance) it was retrieved from. Let's check:

```
print(SomeClass.hello)  # <bound method SomeClass.hello of <class '__main__.SomeClass'>>
print(DerivedClass.hello)  # <bound method SomeClass.hello of <class '__main__.DerivedClass'>>
```

If you want to save and restore the original value of `hello` for `SomeClass`, you cannot use the object access. Let's use `__dict__` instead:

```
hello = SomeClass.__dict__['hello']
print(hello)  # <classmethod at 0x12345678>
SomeClass.hello = lambda: 'replacement'
print(DerivedClass.hello())  # 'replacement'
SomeClass.hello = hello
print(DerivedClass.hello())  # 'DerivedClass'
```

(And yes, of course, mocking is a code smell - all code for explanatory purposes only.)

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you for pointing me in the right directrion!